# How do I access an object from another class in java?

Tags: java

How do I access an object from another java file?

Class1.java:

```
public class Class1 {
Classx obj = new Classx(); //Classx is another public class, in another file, i'm just making an object in Class1.
}
```

Class2.java:

```
public class Class2{
    System.out.println(obj.property); // this doesn't work.
}
```

Why is obj.property not accessible in Class2?

Comment: Please show `Class2` definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one thing is you can't run some arbitrary line of code (System.out.println) in a class definition, so your example is invalid.

`obj` is an "instance variable" in Class1 — Class 2 would need to have a *reference* to an object of Class1 in order to access the "obj" member of that instance.

```
// in Classx.java
public class Classx {
}

// in Class1.java
public class Class1 {
    Classx obj = new Classx();
}

// in Class2.java
public class Class2 {
    Class1 anObj = new Class1();
    public void showIt() {
        System.out.println(anObj.obj);
    }
}

// in TestProg.java
public class TestProg {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Class2 two = new Class2();
        two.showIt();
    }
}
```

Since `obj` in Class1 is not declared *public*, indeed no modifier is given, it has the default access which is *package*, so Class1 and Class2 would need to be in the same package to allow this use of `anObj.obj`.

Answer (score 1):

**Private Objects**

```
public class Class1 
{
  //...
  Classx obj = new Classx();
  //...
  public Classx getClassx()
  {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class Class2
{
  //...
   Class1 c1 = new Class1();
   System.out.println(c1.getClassx().property);
}
```

---

**Public Objects**

```
public class Class1 
{
  public Classx obj = new Classx();
  //...
}
```

and

```
public class Class2
{
  //...
   Class1 c1 = new Class1();
   System.out.println(c1.obj.property);
}
```

---

**Static public  Objects**

```
public class Class1 
{
  //...
  public static Classx obj = new Classx();
  //...
 }
```

and

```
public class Class2
{
  System.out.println(Class1.obj.property);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access fields that are located in a different class, you need to use dot notation. In this case, to access the `obj` field, you would need to use an instance of `Class1`.

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
//Code to instantiate all the variables, etc.
System.out.println(c1.obj.property);
```

The above code assumes that `property` is a field in `Classx`.

If the `obj` field were declared `static`, you would be able to access it with the class itself, rather than with an instance:

```
System.out.println(Class1.obj.property);
```

In practice, fields like this are usually declared `private`, in which case an accessor method may be provided to access it.